# issue refer to scope of variable

Tags: react-native

how to get variable from outer layer method

trying to use a variable in outer layer in my React-Native App

```
updateCheckBox() {
        Constants.TABS.map((item) => {//Constants.TABS is an array
                AsyncStorage.getItem(item)//using item as key to fetch from AsyncStorage
                .then((res) => {
                    if(res == 1) {
                        //debugged here, item was undeined. but i need setState here with item as key. How should i get item here.
                        this.setState({item: true}) // I need to get the item here, but it show undefined
                    } else {
                        this.setState({item:false}) // I need to get the item here, but it show undefined
                    } 
                })
        })
    }
```

// I need to get the item here, but it show undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `item` in `[]` to use it as a `key` for a `property`. Like this:

```
updateCheckBox() {
        Constants.TABS.map(item => {
                AsyncStorage.getItem(key) //
                .then((res) => {
                    //item is accessible here, to use item as the key to a property wrap it in [] 
                    if(res == 1) {
                        this.setState({[item]: true});
                    } else {
                        this.setState({[item]: false});
                    } 
                })
        })
    }
```

Comment: thanks, I will try your code , but i doubt it can work. You changed AsyncStorage.getItem(item) to AsyncStorage.getItem(key), but i need use item here to fetch AsyncStorage.

Comment: Any reason why you are using `.map`? Why not just use `.forEach`? And can you please show your `TABS` array?

Comment: TABS is just a normal array like this: const TABS = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test3"];  About the forEach and map, i thought they are the same to loop an Array, so i picked up map with no reason.

Comment: I used this code and got valid result:
`
["history"].map(item => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(item)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(item, "item is here", res);
        });
    });
`

Comment: @Victor `.map` returns a new array from the values you return inside its function while `.forEach` iterates over the array and returns nothing.

Comment: your code works, i guess my ENV has bug. just see my comment in the end

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found there is no issue in this code, the thing is

```
updateCheckBox() {
    Constants.TABS.map((item) => {
            let key = item
            AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(item, "item is here", res); //item is  visible here
                console.log(key) //key is all always undefined 
                if(res == 1) {
                    this.setState({item: true}) 
                } else {
                    this.setState({item:false}) 
                } 
            })
    })
}
```

key is not visible in method then, which I can not explain, but all in all, my code works.

Comment: Did you try setting the item globally like "this.item = item" and accessing it in your setState?

Comment: Try replacing the console.log with `let newItem = item;` and then accessing the `newItem` in your `setState`.

Comment: @thecodrr thanks for reply, the item is actually from the callback function in map. I updated the code above and made comment